# JTW White-list performance

Tags: node.js, database, redis, jwt

I'm developing a small application in Node.js that will run inside an AWS LightSail, it will probably handle around 500 users/day.

I'm planing to use a JWT White-List to function as a true Logout system, but since I'm still a junior developer and this is my first "complex project" I don't know if it is better to use REDIS just for that or create a simple table inside my already existing database to handle this.
(I know how to use it, that is not the problem, my question is related to unnecessary complexity in the early stages)

Is creating a Redis database just for that more harmful than helpful for my application?

Comment: What do you mean by "true Logout system" ?

Comment: As far as I know, when you logout with a JWT you just erase the Token from the client side, and without this token the user will not be able to use the API. But if someone stole this token before the user request for a logout, the malicious "user" will be able to access the API as if it was the original user until the token expires by time. To prevent that I was told that keeping a database with all the logged in tokens is a good security measure, because when a user request a logout, you drop his/her token from the database, denying any further uses of that token.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand the security issue. I would say only use Redis if there is no budget constraint or infrastructure constraint. Using Redis definitely will be faster because it's in memory Data Structure but based on the 500 users /day statistics, storing the token info in Database would be absolutely fine.  Lets say 500 users login everyday and don't logout for 30 days, you need to store 15000 tokens, which would be fast even with a normal database. Anyway, I think the tokens will expire much before 30 days, just assumed that you may allow keep logged in feature.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, as you showed even with a 30 day token expiration period and 500 new and unique access each day the database would still be small, and fast enough for my needs. I will probably use something around 3 to 7 days for the expiration period, so this number would be even smaller. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: No Problem. I also got to learn a lot.